# Saving related data in MVC (cakephp)

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, save

I'm reading again and again the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) from `cakephp` without understand how to save related data. I have a section called `Works` and a section called Furnitures which can contain `Images`:

  **Works**
- id
- title
- body
- url
- user_id
- created
- modified
- active

  **Furnitures**
- id
- title
- body
- url
- user_id
- created
- modified
- active

  **Images**
- id
- name
- type
- filepath
- user_id
- created
- modified
- active

I've created one MVC for every entity (`Work`, `Furniture` and `Image`), and now I'm trying to add a `Work` to my site with the `add` view:

```
<script>/* script for .add_image, Work and other models can have 0 or more images */</script>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Work.title', array('value'=>'titolo', 'label' => 'Nome lavoro')); ?></div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Work.body', array('type' => 'textarea', 'value'=>'description', 'label' => 'Descrizione')); ?></div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Work.url', array('value'=>'http://', 'label'=> false)); ?></div>
<div>Immagini</div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->input('Image.name', array('label'=> false, 'value'=>'Nome immagine'));?></div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->file('Image.file'); ?></div>
<div><div class="add_image">Add image</div></div>
<div><?php echo $this->Form->end('Inserisci lavoro'); ?></div>
```

This saves only the `Work` data, without `Image` related, I suppose I'm missing something in the `Model` and in the `Controller`:

```
<?php

class Work extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Work';
    var $belongsTo = array ('User');
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
        'Image' => array (
            'className' => 'Image',
            'order' => 'Image.created DESC',
            'exclusive' => true,
            'dependent' => true // this will remove all images related to article
        ),
        'Tag' => array (
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'order' => 'Tag.name DESC'
        )
    );

    var $validate = array (
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 60),
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'body' => array (
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 250),
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'url' => array (
            'rule' => array('url', true),
            'allowEmpty' => true
        )
    );

    function parentNode () {
        return null;
    }
}

?>
```

WorksController:

```
<?php

class WorksController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Works';
    var $components = array ('Session');

    function index () {
        $this->set('works', $this->Work->find('all'));
    }

    function view () {
        $this->Work->id = $id;
        $this->set('work', $this->Work->read());
    }

    function add () {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $work = $this->Work->save($this->data);
            if (!empty($work)) {
                // this is wrong, but what should I write?
                // $this->data['Image']['user_id'] = $this->Work->User->id;
                // $this->Work->Image->saveAll($this->data);
                $this->Session->setFlash ('Lavoro inserito correttamente');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

ImageModel:

```
<?php

class Image extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Image';

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array (
        'Work' => array (
            'className' => 'Work'
        ),
        'Furniture' => array (
            'className' => 'Furniture'
        )
    );

    var $actsAs = array ('FileUpload.FileUpload' => array (
        'uploadDir' => 'img/shared',// 'forceWebroot' => true, is default
        'allowedTypes' => array(
            'jpg' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
            'jpeg' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'), 
            'gif' => array('image/gif'),
            'png' => array('image/png','image/x-png'),
        ),
        'maxFileSize' => 614400, // 600kB in bytes
        'unique' => true
    ));

    // in the wiew file: echo $form->input('Image.file', array('type' => 'file'));

    var $validate = array (
        'name' => array (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Nome dell\'immagine in fase di cariamento mancante'
        ),
        'filename' => array (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Nome dell\'immagine in fase di cariamento mancante'
        )
    );
}
?>
```

This saves only part of of `Works` data:

  **Works**
- id - ok
- title - ok
- body - ok
- url - ok
- user_id **- is 0**
- created - ok
- modified - ok
- active **- is 0**

How should I implement `Images` in the `Works`?

I thought to add a db table named `images_works` to link `Works` with `Images` and `furnitures_images` to link `Furnitures` with `Images`, what should I do to continue and fix the `user_id missing error`?

Comment: Aren't you missing your foreign keys in the database? Without a related foreign key there is no way for Cake to see how things fit together, even if you define them in your models.

Answer (score 0):

first

```
<?php
class WorkdsController extends AppController
    var $components = array('Session', 'Auth');
    if($this->Wok->create($data) && $this->Work->save($this->data)){
        $work_id = $this->Work->getID;
        // and than use work_id work with work id. then you should somehow get user_id
        // for example $this->Auth->user(id');
    }
}
```

then if you want to link images to works in the way you have described above (hasMany) then you should add a work_id to images table.

otherwise create a new table images_works (id, image_id, work_id) and use $hasAndBelongsToMany, instead of $hasMay

Comment: first thanks for your precious help, it return an error `Notice (8): Undefined variable: data [APP/controllers/works_controller.php, line 21]` i think is in `if($this->Work->create($data) && $this->Work->save($this->data))`, could you fix it please?

Comment: ok fixed `$this->Work->create($this->data)` and `$this->Work->getID();`

Comment: now the `user_id` works fine, but `images_works` has all `user_id`, `work_id` and `image_id` to `0` and the `images` table still empty

Answer (score 0):

The input's name must be different and according to data structure that CakePHP expect for Image to saveAll(). Either make the name to be [Image][*counter*][name] or [*Counter*][Image][name]. (Not sure which one it is that cake model expect) Or else you'll receive the only one image and only one image will be saved.

Also make sure the form element has the attribute `enctype` set for file upload.